# Condition for convergent sequence in Post Office metric?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ be the metric space consisting of $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric. Let $x$ in and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$, we consider the distance $d$ given by $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases} |x| + |y| &\text{if}\,\,\,\,x\neq y \\ 0 &\text{if}\,\,\,\, x=y \end{cases}$$

with $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $r>0$. Let $(x_n)$ a sequence of real numbers and $x\ne 0$. give a simple condition on $(x_n)$ so that it converges to $x$.

My attempt:

For each $r>0$ there is an $n_r \in\Bbb N$ such that for all $n\ge n_r$,

$d(x_n, x)<r$

so $|x_n| + |x|<r$

I can't get this condition

Any help will be appreciated

thanks you

Comment: "I do not understand what they mean by xn is on the radial line through x", well, me neither, as you did not mention that in your question.

Comment: Also you write $|x_n|+|y|$ but there is no $y$ in your context.

Comment: @CaptainLama Thank you I edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convergence only happens when $x_n$ is eventually constant and equal to $x$. Otherwise take $r < |x|$ to see that you can't satisfy the definition for all $r$.

Comment: Obviously. Please read the question. It specifies $x \neq 0$.

Comment: @RobertBassett thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

First look at how the space looks topologically: if $x \neq 0$, $x$ is an isolated point, i.e. $\{x\}$ is open (it equals the open ball $B(x,|x|)$, and if $x=0$ $d(0,x)=|x|$ as in the usual metric, so $0$ has the same neighbourhoods as the usual topology on $\Bbb R$.

From this starting point you should think about convergence. When is the a term of the sequence $(x_n)$ closer to $x$ than $|x|$?